# Inclusion of <CL/cl.hpp> causes multiple errors

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a piece of code with two header files which works perfectly. However as soon as I include  (not even using any of OpenCL functions), multiple errors occur such as:
C2059 syntax error 'const',
C2059 syntax error ')',
C2065 'T': undeclared identifier.
Is there a known reason for an OpenCL library to cause such errors?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as we can't diagnose the issue simply from being told you used a header. I will say that with respect to CL-HPP, you should be using `<CL/cl2.hpp>` instead, as it's a more up-to-date version of the wrapper, and there are numerous bugfixes and design revisions that weren't ported into the original header.

Comment: @Xirema
Sorry, I'm a beginner and using this for the first time.  Four similar templates like this one:
`template <typename T>
inline vec2<T> min(const vec2<T> &v1, const vec2<T> &v2)
{
 return vec2<T>(std::min(v1.x, v2.x), std::min(v1.y, v2.y));
}`   give these errors when CL/cl.hpp is included:  

C2988 unrecognizable template declaration/definition 
C2059 syntax error: 'const'

Comment: You need to put your entire code in the body of the problem. Again, we can't diagnose problems unless we have the context for the program. Read the link I provided on how to pair down your code to just the parts of the code that replicate the error.

Comment: @Xirema, yeah, will do next time. Actually my supervisor found a problem, errors only occur if you include <CL/cl.hpp> before all other libraries, so the solution was rather simple - include OpenCL last.